# How Exactly To Use a Global Variable?

Tags: objective-c, global-variables

I'm a beginner with Objective-C, and am trying to use a global variable. I know that this question has been asked a hundred times, but none of the answers have worked for me. **I'm trying to declare a BOOL variable in one class, and check its value in another.** This is what I'm working with:
SController.h:

```
@interface SController : UIViewController {
    BOOL leftSide;
    BOOL rightSide;

}
```

SController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 leftSide = YES;
 rightSide = YES;
}
```

Now, for the class I'm trying to access the value of the BOOLs in:

```
#import "SController.h"
@interface VViewController : UIViewController
{
}
```

And VViewController's .m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
// See what the BOOL values from SController are.
}
```

**What I've tried:**
Going off of the previous related questions on here, I've tried putting "extern" in front of the BOOLs declaration in SController.h, but that did not work. I tried simply importing the SControllers header file into VViewController, and that did not work either. I'm very new to Objective-C and programming in general, so I'm having a tough time wrapping my head around basic concepts like this. I understand the potential issues surrounding using a global variable, but this program is very small and for personal use. If anyone can show me what to change to make this happen, that would be great.

Comment: These are not global variables, but ivars. To declare a global variable declare it outside the class declaration, in the header or implementation file.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri Oh thanks, that would explain why none of the answers were helping me. I'll give that a shot now.

Comment: In SController you should define two property. In VViewController you will check like delegate.leftSide and delegate.rightSide. Where delegate is the object of the SController.

Comment: Just because the app is small and for personal use doesn't mean it should be coded badly if you're just learning. Learn to do it right. Why do you want a global variable? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Wain That's a good point, thank you. I want to use one mostly out of convenience. The only way the I can set the leftSide and rightSide variables is in that single view controller. I need to see their values in the second view controller to execute accordingly.

Comment: So, rather than use globals you should use the relationship between the view controllers, or pass the appropriate information when the view controllers are created / shown, or use a singleton as the global and have it mediate access to the information.

Comment: @Wain Alright thank you. I'm unsure of how to do that but I will research right now.

Comment: +1 No need to downvote the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the others said, don't use a global variable for that (and most other) purpose.

You created iVars and in order to access them, you need to expose them to other objects.
You generally do that by defining @properties in your `SController`s header file. When doing that, you don't need to create iVars yourself, they are created implicitly. And methods to access the iVars are also automagically created (getters and setters).

Your SControllers header could look something like this:

```
@interface SController: UIViewController
//no need to declare the iVars here, they are created by the @property definitions

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL leftSide;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL rightSide;

@end
```

In your other viewController you need a reference to the instance of SController you previously created and want to "talk" to (it is important you understand this), then you could access the instance variable through the generated getter/setter methods like so:

```
//this is "dot notation", the first line would be equivalent
//to writing: [sControllerInstance setLeftSide: YES]
sControllerInstance.leftSide = YES;
BOOL valueRightSide = sControllerInstance.rightSide;
```

Please read up on: objective-c properties, getters/setters and dot notation.
You will find plenty of information on google and SO

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the answer you're looking for, but try rethinking your app. Global variables is not the best way to go for Object oriented programming.

Answer (score 0):

Create GlobalVariable.h header class file and defined following externs as follows

```
extern NSString * googleURL;
```

And then in your implementation GlobalVariable.m file

```
#import "GlobalVariable.h"

NSString * googleURL = @"www.google.co.uk";
```

And then import the class wherever you want to use it across.

Answer (score 0):

By default the variables (as defined in your code) are protected.  You can add the @public keyword before the 2 variables to make them public but it's not recommended.  Generally you want to expose those as properties using the @property keyword

Example:

```
@interface SController : UIViewController {

    @public
    BOOL leftSide;
    BOOL rightSide;

    @protected
    //other protected variables here
}
```